# RuntimeError Loading KML Data in CesiumJS

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, cesiumjs

Encountering a RuntimeError while attempting to load KML data using CesiumJS. The error occurs during the process and seems to be related to KmlDataSource.js. Looking for guidance on debugging strategies or known solutions to resolve this issue.

Error Message and Stack Trace:
KmlDataSource.js:1846 RuntimeError message: ""\n"name: "RuntimeError"stack: "Error\n    at new RuntimeError (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/Core/RuntimeError.js:42:19)\n    at http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/DataSources/KmlDataSource.js:1835:35\n    at Promise.then (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:196:34)\n    at http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:297:13\n    at processQueue (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:647:4)\n    at _resolve (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:333:4)\n    at promiseResolve (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:359:11)\n    at Promise.then (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:196:34)\n    at http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:298:7\n    at processQueue (http://localhost/mvc/Content/Cesium/Source/ThirdParty/when.js:647:4)"[[Prototype]]: Object"
Problem:

The error occurs during the loading or processing of KML data within CesiumJS.
I've reviewed the code around line 1835 in KmlDataSource.js but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause.
It seems related to asynchronous operations or promises within the KmlDataSource.js file.

Steps Taken:
Inspected the code around line 1835 in KmlDataSource.js for potential issues.
Verified that the KML file complies with the KML specification and doesn't contain any visible errors.
Implemented basic logging but haven't successfully traced the flow leading to the error.

Request:
I'm seeking guidance on troubleshooting this issue within CesiumJS's KmlDataSource.js. Any insights, debugging strategies, or known solutions related to RuntimeError during KML data loading in CesiumJS would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!